# Is there a way to silence uninteresting calls to StrictMock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I have a situation where I need to test that a method is (mostly) called precisely in the right situations. Therefore I use StrictMock for doing this because that whats it for.

However I have a situation where a call is optional, in fact it happens to be called.

What is the preferred way to handle this? The straight forward way would be to just add an EXPECT_CALL, but the documentation says not to use EXPECT_CALL if there is no real expectation on the call.

Comment: Just add expectation that this call is expected at least zero times. Or don't use `StrictMock`.

Comment: Agree, it's fine to use `EXPECT_CALL(`...`).Times(AnyNumber())` to ignore whether a specific mocked function is called or not. "Consider these calls expected if they happen."